# is it possible that some network packets are with null bytes?

Tags: c, network-programming

in network programming
usually we use `recv()` or `recvfrom()` for receiving packets
one of the argument is a string buffer,like

```
 char buf[2000];
 recv(sockfd, buf, len, 0);
```

I'm wondering whether there are some null bytes( `0` or `\0`) in a packet
if so, how to deal with this?
thanks

Comment: What's so special about these `NUL` (**not** `null`, that's something in JavaScript) bytes that makes you wonder?

Comment: in C, I'm afraid there are `NUL` bytes, is it possible or not?

Comment: @userXXX It is, why wouldn't it be possible?

Comment: You are not dealing with with 0 terminated strings here, so you cannot use `strlen` and similar functions. `recv` returns length of the received data, that's what telling you how much data you got

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it's possible. How to handle them depends on the communication protocol.

But remember that [recv](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv) returns the number of bytes recieved, and it can be smaller than the buffer size.